# Run Fusuma on startup

Tags: gnome, touchpad, asus

I recently change to Ubuntu (18.04) from Windows on my Asus laptop (ref no: X456U) and the only thing I'm missing are the touch gestures of my asus my touchpad...
Trying to fix that I installed [FUSUMA](https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma) and when I run it on the terminal it works fine while keeping that terminal window open.

But now I want it to run on startup and it is not working...
at first I try just adding `fusuma` and then with`/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 & fusuma"` (trying to delay the execution which seems to be the problem according to the internet)

[image: As you can see on the image:]

Any solutions for running fusuma on startup or for the touch gestures? [Gnome version and system information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqZvs.png)

Comment: your `sleep 15 & fusuma` means: Run `sleep 15` and **parallel** already execute `fusuma`. If you want them to run sequencial you have to put a double `&&` between them.

Comment: Take a look here - https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma#autostart-gnome-session-properties
It will give you the steps needed to have fusuma load on login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check where you installed fusuma.

```
which fusuma
```

Then, add the location you got to Startup Applications.

Comment: The OP says he can run it from the terminal by running `fusuma`. So the autostart terminal will be able to do the same.

Comment: search for startup application and add the path to the command field and reboot to test the application